How to link from a GitLab wiki to an image in the repository and show it without having to click?
I have to store a lot of data in a database. To ease the task I wrote some software that stores the data in the database and documents the software in markdown format. Next the documentation is stored in the Gitlab project wiki. Part of the documentation are some basic statistics that give the user of the data some initial insights. The (Python) software also generates graphs, barcharts and such that should be displayed in the wiki. I don’t know how to do that. The information on it is conflicting or simply does not work.
As I see it I have to store the images in an images directory of the repository and commit/merge the changes. Trouble is that I don’t see how to link to that image from the wiki. Something like [image](https://<url>/images/image.png) doesn’t work, neither do a lot of variations like main/images/image.jpg or whatever.
I can link to the link that the browser shows when opening the image. But that links to the repository position of the images and does not open it. However, what I want is that the image shows in the wiki without having to click anything. Is that possible?
Anyone any idea how to do this?

markdown image syntax is ![alt text](image.png)

Where is this image.png?
